# While assigning a lot of fields which one of the these two formats is preferred?

Tags: coding-style

While assigning a lot of fields which one of the following two formats is preferred

1) One whitespace around the operator, something that pep8 would recommend in python.

```
 field1 = field1value
 field2_with_large_name = field2value
 field3 = field3value
 field4 = field4value
 field5_with_large_name = field5value
 field6_midlegth = field6value
 field7_with_large_name = field7value
 field8 = field8value
 field9 = field9value
```

2) A more readable tabular form:

```
 field1                 = field1value
 field2_with_large_name = field2value
 field3                 = field3value
 field4                 = field4value
 field5_with_large_name = field5value
 field6_midlegth        = field6value
 field7_with_large_name = field7value
 field8                 = field8value
 field9                 = field9value
```

Comment: Both forms are bad. You must rethink the architecture to avoid such assignments.

Comment: @Riateche: It's not pretty, but sometimes rethinking the architecture is not an option, and manually assigning all those fields is the only practical way.

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow, as it calls for discussion and opinion. [This is not a discussion group or chat site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128550/172661). Voting to close as "not constructive". (The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) also mentions discussion questions as being inappropriate for the question-and-answer format here.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think one approach is better or worse than the other. I usually go with the first option (less work to format), but I like the second option for situations where the values are related and there is a benefit to being able to quickly scan and compare them.

One thing I'd mention with regards to the second approach is that it might be better to use spaces than tabs for alignment. A tab is not a consistent unit, since one programmer might have their editor set to represent a tab with 4 spaces, while another programmer will prefer 2. When one programmer views the other's code the alignment will be destroyed.

Of course if your editor is set to convert tabs to spaces, so that the code doesn't actually contain tabs, then this is a non-issue.